# ip module returning different ip addresses

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, ip

I am using the ip library of npm.
I have two config files, one for React and one for Node, for the same application.

```
const ip = require('ip');
console.log(ip.address());
```

This returns different ip addresses for the React config file(inside the src folder-127.0.0.1) and Node server file(outside the src folder - IPv4 address).

The issue is that I am pretty sure that I ran the exact same code earlier and it gave me the same ip addresses for both as then I was able to access my webpages. I need the same ip to make requests to my node backend, I cannot afford it in production. Are there other definite methods of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You get different ip results because 2 method call `ip.address()` are using different network interfaces.

To make `ip.address()` return identical result, you can pass network interface name as the first parameter, such as `en0`:

```
const ip = require('ip');
console.log(ip.address('en0'));
```

p.s. To get all current networks interface names, `os.networkInterfaces()` can be used.

Update: OP try to get IP address in React code, in browser side. This is mission impossible. Otherwise, it would bring huge security problem.

Update 2: OP don't want to store endpoint IP address in frontend code for security reason, neither want to retrieve the IP address first (network overhead issue). In this case, you can make a proxy in server. All frontend know is interacting with current server, the data exchange is delivered by server as:

Browser <--> Server <--> Various endpoint IP

The steps are:

1. The server (that host the frontend code) get request from browser
2. Server check which endpoint would be used for that client
3. Server send the request to specific endpoint
4. Server get response from endpoint
5. Server return the response in above step to browser

Comment: 'en0' does not work: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: @AbdulAhad `en0` is just an example. Different computer and OS have different network interface name. You need to list the current network interface names first. Either by `os.networkInterfaces()` in Node.js, or by running command `ifconfig` or `ipconfig`

Comment: os.networkInterfaces() runs perfectly when I run it in the server file but in the config file for react inside the src folder, it shows an empty object.

Comment: Do you mean you are running `os.networkInterfaces()` in browser side?

Comment: Yes, I know I should be making a request to node to get the address, isn't there a workaround to get my ip without this overhead?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's impossible to get os level network information in browser. Otherwise, it would be huge security problem.

Comment: So, in production do I just give the name for my server as localhost or the ip address, in order to make requests to my backend. ( both are on the same machine)

Comment: In production, you need to define the domain or ip address of server, and use that in browser code. p.s. browser code and server code are NOT running "on the same machine".

Comment: I meant to say that my front end code and backend code are on the same machine. And I do not want to hardcode the ip address

Comment: Frontend code is executed on browser (various different machines), so you can hardcode the IP address, or, send request to server that host the frontend code, fetching which IP address should the current browser use.

Comment: I am aware that I can do that but it is not considered to be a good practice. And I did not want to add overheads of fetching ip address too. Hence, the question, any other more secure ways you are aware of?

Comment: Ah, maybe you can use proxy. Please check my answer update.